# Moving average with successive elements using awk

Tags: bash, awk

I am trying to write a script in which each row element will give the average of next N rows (including itself). I know how to do it with preceding rows like the Nth row will give the average of the preceding N rows. Here is the script for that

```
awk '
BEGIN{
       N = 5;
     }

     { 
       x = $2;
       i = NR % N;
       aveg += (x - X[i]) / N;
       X[i] = x;
       print $1, $2, aveg; 
     }' < file > aveg.txt
```

where file looks like this

```
     1       1
     2       2
     3       3
     4       4
     5       5
     6       6
     7       7
     8       8
     9       9
    10      10
    11      11
    12      12
    13      13
    14      14
    15      15
    16      16
    17      17
    18      18
    19      19
    20      20
    21      21
    22      22
    23      23
    24      24
    25      25
    26      26
    27      27
    28      28
    29      29
    30      30
    31      31
    32      32
    33      33
    34      34
    35      35
    36      36
    37      37
    38      38
    39      39
    40      40
```

I want that the first row has average of the next 5 elements i.e.

```
 (1+2+3+4+5)/5=3
 second row (2+3+4+5+6)/5=4
 third row  (3+4+5+6+7)/5=5
```

and so on. The rows should look like

```
    1        1       3  
    2        2       4
    3        3       5
    4        4       6   ...
```

Can it be done as simply as the script shown above? I was thinking of assigning the row value as the value of nth row below and then proceeding with the above script. But, unfortunately I am unable to assign the row value to some value down the file. Can someone help me to write this script and find the moving average. I am open to other commands in shell as well.

Comment: You would need to read and save the next n lines to a variable. It would work the exact same way as preceding rows,

Comment: Can you please suggest an example on how to do it because I am not able to figure out how to store n elements in one variable.

Comment: What should the output be for rows near the end of the input file that don't have 5 lines after them? Why not make this a problem of averaging 3 lines at a time from a sample that's, say, 5 lines long so you can concisely show all of the sample input/output?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$ cat test.awk
BEGIN {
    N=5            # the window size
}
{
    n[NR]=$1       # store the value in an array
} 
NR>=N {            # for records where NR >= N
    x=0            # reset the sum variable
    delete n[NR-N] # delete the one out the window of N
    for(i in n)    # all array elements
        x+=n[i]    # ... must be summed
    print n[NR-(N-1)],x/N  # print the row from the beginning of window
}                          # and the related window average
```

Try it:

```
$ for i in {1..36}; do echo $i $i >> test.in ; done
$ awk -f test.awk test.in
1 3
2 4
3 5
...
30 32
31 33
32 34
```

It could be done in running sum, add current and subtract `n[NR-N]`, like this:

```
BEGIN {
    N=5
} 
{
    n[NR]=$1
    x+=$1-n[NR-N]
} 
NR>=N {
    delete n[NR-N]
    print n[NR-(N-1)],x/N
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I am trying to understand every bit of the script. When you say

     for(i in n)
why does it sum only 5 elements

Comment: Because I keep only array elements `n[NR], n[NR-1], n[NR-2], ...` and `delete n[NR-N]`, ie. when `N=5` and script is on record or row `NR=6` I `delete n[6-5]`.

Answer (score 1):

Using a N-sized array

```
BEGIN { N=5 }

{
  s+=array[i++]=$1

  if (i>=N) i=0
}

NR>=N {
        print array[i], s/N
        s-=array[i]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { OFS="\t"; range=5 }
{ recs[NR%range] = $0 }
NR >= range {
    sum = 0
    for (i in recs) {
        split(recs[i],flds)
        sum += flds[2]
    }
    print recs[(NR+1-range)%range], sum / range
}
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
1       1       3
2       2       4
3       3       5
4       4       6
5       5       7
6       6       8
7       7       9
8       8       10
9       9       11
10      10      12
11      11      13
12      12      14
13      13      15
14      14      16
15      15      17
16      16      18
17      17      19
18      18      20
19      19      21
20      20      22
21      21      23
22      22      24
23      23      25
24      24      26
25      25      27
26      26      28
27      27      29
28      28      30
29      29      31
30      30      32
31      31      33
32      32      34
33      33      35
34      34      36
35      35      37
36      36      38
```